# MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException Selenium IE9/FireFox

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox, selenium

I've encountered a problem with FireFox/IE9 driver with selenium. When I use the Actions class of selenium and use its method moveToElement, it wont move to the element and it would return a MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException. I've tried to used others solutions like using Coordinates, Point and javascriptexecutor and all of them didn't worked. By using the moveToElement, It worked on my chrome driver so i don't know why it wont work on firefox33/IE9 as they are native to selenium

Here is my snippet of the code:

```
WebElement requiredCheckbox = new WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("tc_n_cs_subscribe_1")));

    // Point points = requiredCheckbox.getLocation();
    // System.out.println(points.getX());
    // System.out.println(points.getY());
    // actions.moveByOffset(points.getX(), points.getY()).perform();

    // ((JavascriptExecutor)
    // driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, "+points.getY()+");");

    // ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
    // "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", requiredCheckbox);

    // Coordinates coordinate =
    // ((Locatable)requiredCheckbox).getCoordinates();
    // coordinate.onPage();
    // coordinate.inViewPort();

    actions.moveToElement(requiredCheckbox).build().perform();

    requiredCheckbox.click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this. I used the javascriptexecutor code.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
        "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", requiredCheckbox);
```

It worked after I added DesiredCapabilities setJavascriptEnabled method.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? If you want to scroll the view to requiredCheckbox, try

```
((Locatable) requiredCheckbox).getCoordinates().inViewPort();
```